# GLSL Texture Mapping

Tags: glsl, texture-mapping

I want to do texture mapping with GLSL. But I guess my code doesn't use shaders. Here is my codes:

Vertex.vert

```
#version 330


out vec2 texcoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position=gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix*gl_Vertex;
    texcoord=gl_MultiTexCoord0.xy;
}
```

Fragment.frag

```
#version 330

uniform sampler2D img;
in vec2 texcoord;

void main()
{
    vec4 texcolor = texture2D(img,texcoord);
    gl_FragColor=texcolor;

}
```

The texture mapping part in main

```
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textureId[0]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);      
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader.ShaderProgram,"img"),0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-2.5f, -2.5f, 2.5f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(2.5f, -2.5f, 2.5f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(2.5f, -2.5f, -2.5f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-2.5f, -2.5f, -2.5f);
    glEnd();
```

What is wrong with my code?
The full codes:

http://codepad.org/O096OoKU

http://codepad.org/m3Snroyv

http://codepad.org/8zvJ4Vrp

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the shader code is ok. however you never called 
glGetAttribLocation()
glGetUniformLocation()

before calling gluniform(), glVertexAttribPointer()

also you have to call glUseProgram()  one time shortly before all these are calling .

Comment: If you look at the firs link I call    shader.CompileShaders();    before mainloop.  glUseProgram() is in that. But how can I use the functions you mentioned? If it is simple can you write it?

Comment: That glUsePrograme() have to be called before each call  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_TextureMainInput);
glUniform1i(textures[0][displayMode], 0); where are these ?

Comment: I added those but there is no change. There is no change whether add them or not the code runs normally, shaders aren't being used. Can you give me a internet link to learn them?

Comment: Follow the rule, 1. compile, link , use shader code  2. call glgetattribute, glgetuniform function to get handler 3. push values to glsl through that handler like calling glUniformxx(handler,value) glVertexAttribPointer(handler,value)

Comment: No, I mean this specific issue, texture mapping with glsl. I look many examples but still I can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

im new at this too so correct me if im wrong but perhaps its supposed to be something like this instead?
so instead of glTexCoord2f and glVertex2f you always use glVertexAttrib2f and 3f combined 
with layout(location = ???) instead.

upvote if this works for you guys.

some deprecated that i tried. glMultiTexCoord gl_texCoord

```
#ifdef __VERT__
#version 330

uniform mat4 cameraPV;
uniform mat4 lightPV;

layout(location = 0) in vec3 shader_vertexPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 shader_textureCoord;

out vec2 shader_baseTextureCoord;
out vec4 shader_lightTextureCoord;

void main()
{
    vec4 worldPosition = vec4(shader_vertexPosition, 1);
    gl_Position = cameraPV * worldPosition;
    shader_baseTextureCoord = shader_textureCoord;
    shader_lightTextureCoord = lightPV * worldPosition;
}
#endif

static void VertexAttrib(GLuint location, glm::vec3 vector)
{
    glVertexAttrib3f(location, vector.x, vector.y, vector.z);
}

glm::vec3 pa(+50, -10, -50);
glm::vec3 pb(-50, -10, -50);
glm::vec3 pc(+50, -10, +50);
glm::vec3 pd(-50, -10, +50);

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    glVertexAttrib2f(1, 1, 0); GLMisc::VertexAttrib(0, pa);
    glVertexAttrib2f(1, 0, 0); GLMisc::VertexAttrib(0, pb);
    glVertexAttrib2f(1, 1, 1); GLMisc::VertexAttrib(0, pc);
    glVertexAttrib2f(1, 0, 1); GLMisc::VertexAttrib(0, pd);
glEnd();
```